# What is the shortest way to accept different inputs from a user and make it trigger the exact same section of code

Tags: java

I am wondering what is the shortest way to accept different inputs from a user and make it trigger the exact same section of code. For instance, if I have `if(userInputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("quarterly"))` and i want it to accept different inputs (q, qrtly, etc.) to trigger the same section of code, what would I do? Any help appreciated! :)

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Interest

{

    static double userInputDou;

    static String userInputStr;

    static double rate;

    static double time;

    static double principal;

    static double interest;

    static double subinterest;

    static double cNum;

    static double total;

    static Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {

            System.out.println("Would you like to calculate simple interest or compound interest?");

            userInputStr = myScanner.nextLine();



            if(userInputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("simple interest"))

            {

                System.out.println("Please enter the rate: ");



                if(myScanner.hasNextDouble())

                    {

                        userInputDou = myScanner.nextDouble();

                        rate = (userInputDou / 100);

                    }

                else

                    {

                        System.out.println("Please enter a integer for the rate.");

                        System.exit(0);

                    }

                System.out.println("Please enter the time: ");



                if(myScanner.hasNextDouble())

                    {

                        userInputDou = myScanner.nextDouble();

                        time = userInputDou;

                    }

                else

                    {

                        System.out.println("Please enter an integer for the time.");

                        System.exit(0);

                    }

                System.out.println("Please enter the principal: ");



                if(myScanner.hasNextDouble())

                    {

                        userInputDou = myScanner.nextDouble();

                        principal = userInputDou;

                    }

                else

                    {

                        System.out.println("Please enter an integer for the principal.");

                        System.exit(0);

                    }

                interest = (principal * rate * time);



                System.out.println("Your interest is $" + interest);

                System.out.println("Your total payment is $" + (interest + principal));

            }

            else if(userInputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("compound interest"))

            {

                System.out.println("Please enter the rate: ");



                if(myScanner.hasNextDouble())

                    {

                        userInputDou = myScanner.nextDouble();

                        rate = (userInputDou / 100);

                    }

                else

                    {

                        System.out.println("Please enter a integer for the rate.");

                        System.exit(0);

                    }

                System.out.println("Please enter the time: ");



                if(myScanner.hasNextDouble())

                    {

                        userInputDou = myScanner.nextDouble();

                        time = userInputDou;

                    }

                else

                    {

                        System.out.println("Please enter an integer for the time.");

                        System.exit(0);

                    }

                System.out.println("Please enter the principal: ");



                if(myScanner.hasNextDouble())

                    {

                        userInputDou = myScanner.nextDouble();

                        principal = userInputDou;

                    }

                else

                    {

                        System.out.println("Please enter an integer for the principal.");

                        System.exit(0);

                    }

                System.out.println("Would you like to compound the interest quarterly or annually?");

                userInputStr = myScanner.next();

                if(userInputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("quarterly"))

                {

                    System.out.println("For how many quarters would you like to compound the interest for?");

                    if(myScanner.hasNextDouble())

                    {

                        userInputDou = myScanner.nextDouble();

                        cNum = (userInputDou * 4);

                        subinterest = (principal * (1 + (rate / cNum)));

                        interest = Math.pow(subinterest, (cNum * time));

                        total = (principal + interest); 



                        System.out.println("Your quarterly compounded interest is $" + interest);

                        System.out.println("Your total payment is $" + total);

                    }

                    else

                    {

                        System.out.println("Please enter an integer for the number of quarters.");

                        System.exit(0);

                    }

                }

                else if(userInputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("annually"))

                {

                    cNum = time;

                    subinterest = (principal * (1 + (rate / cNum)));

                    interest = Math.pow(subinterest, time);

                    total = (principal + interest); 



                    System.out.println("Your annually compounded interest is $" + interest);

                    System.out.println("Your total payment is $" + total);  

                }

                else

                {

                    System.out.println("Please enter either 'quarterly' or 'annually'.");

                    System.exit(0);

                }

            }

            else

            {

                System.out.println("Please enter either 'simple interest' or 'compound interest'.");

                System.exit(0);

            }


    }

}
```

Comment: `if(userInputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("quarterly") || userInputStr.equalsIgnoreCase("qrtly"))`

Comment: Or you could try a regular expression, e.g. `if (userInputStr.matches("(?i:quarterly|qrtly|q)"))`